# MySQL DB: Efficient structure for data logging / retreiving by many users

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a web application using php and MySQL. The application is mainly to monitor temperature using embedded devices distributed in many areas.
Each device posts a reading every 2 hours to the DB. I currently have a table with the following columns:

1. Device ID
2. Time and Date (for the reading)
3. Temperature Reading.

my concern is that

1. with time the DB will become very huge, also
2. if i queried the table for a certain device (by device ID), and certain time span (for example last week) this can take long time.

is there a better structure that i can use, maybe using a different table for each device, or different tables for each day (or week).

i'm looking for

1. easy backup,
2. fast responses (less complex query statements)

Comment: The worst thing you can do is split your table into multiple ones. If you want something done properly, and to have any chance at performance - **keep everything** in the same table, just like you did. If you split stuff into multiple tables, all you're doing is making your querying life worse. MySQL will, internally,  keep everything in a single file whether you split stuff into more tables or not - that means you achieved nothing, except you don't have all the data available in a single spot - which you *need* to have available in a single spot.

Comment: To gain performance from relational databases, we don't mess about with table design as much as we optimize the hardware. No matter what design you come up with, if the hardware can't keep up - it will be slow. Take into account how many records you might have and what kind of server is running MySQL (CPU, RAM, size and type of hard drive).